# Ansible yaml anchors and jinja2 templating

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

how do I overwrite the disk attribute while also not hardcoding the number of disks?

This is what I want it (the tasks/main.yml of that role) to do, but it fails with an syntax error and also requires hardcoding the number of disks:

```
---
- name: anchors
  when: false
  debug:
    new_disk:
      - &new_disk
        size_gb: 80
        type: thin
        datastore: '{{ item.datastore }}'
- name: Deploy usage001 vms
  loop: '{{ vms.usage001 }}
  vmware_guest:
    disk:
      - <<: *new_disk
      - <<: *new_disk
        '{{ item.disk[0] }}'
      - <<: *new_disk
        '{{ item.disk[1] }}
```

Where item looks like:

```
vms:
  usage001:
    disk:
      - size_gb: 1000
      - size_gb: 600
  usage002:
    (...)
```

Comment: It looks like this is not possible in ansible. I got this workaround: https://gist.github.com/agaffney/fe154d6045487c3019c48d6de6e7b179
Tl;Dr: use a yaml block the jinja2 replacement happens inside of that string and than use another jinja2 statement to insert the yaml-string using the `from_yaml` filter.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `<<`,  the [Merge Key Language Independent Type](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) states:

> The “<<” merge key is used to indicate that all the keys of one or more specified maps should be inserted into the current map.

But you specify the anchor `new-disk` on a sequence instead of map.

You probably want to do:

```
new_disk: 
  - &new_disk
    size_gb: 80
    type: thin
    datastore: '{{ item.datastore }}'
```

---

You seem to want select `size_gb: 1000` from your `item`, but as the quotes are outside of your jinja2 syntax the substitution, if it works, will result in:

```
  - <<: *new_disk
    'size_gb: 1000'
```

and for that to work it has to be:

```
  - <<: *new_disk
    size_gb: 1000
```

so make sure you get rid of those quotes.

The selection using `item.disk[0]` given your item seems strange as well, I would have expected something like `item.vms.usage001.disk[0]` but that might be my lack of jinja2 specific knowledge.

Comment: That's not the problem. That part works fine. The problem is, how do I integrate the list of disks? from the jinja2 {{ item.disk }}?
And for reference, my anchor syntax is valid according to: https://blog.daemonl.com/2016/02/yaml.html

Comment: I am not telling that your anchor syntax is incorrect. Anchors can be placed on any node. The value for your merge key is incorrect, as that key expects a map ( directly, or more commonly using an alias for an anchored **map**). Your alias is to a **sequence** and that is wrong, and it is also not what the blog you refer to does. In any event I would not believe some blog over the official YAML documentation.

Comment: Ok, fair point. All I wanted to say with my last reply was, even though it's not `official yaml standard` it's still parseable by common yaml parsers and provides the correct output...

Comment: Yes, most parsers support merge keys, assuming your corrected input that should work. So what remains the jinja2 stuff. I updated my answer with additional (potential) solution information, but I don't know jinja2 as well as YAML.

Comment: regarding this: `item.vms.usage001.disk[0]`, that is something ansible specific, the loop statement in the yaml acts as a loop and each element of `vms.usage001` gets inserted into `item` like in a foreach-loop, e.g. ansible parses that section for each input one after another.